# Convert and rearrange range operation in an array

Tags: vba, excel, data-structures

I have the following code. I will explain this step by step.

```
6001    1001    3001
3001    1002    2001
2001    1003    3002
3002    1004    2002
2002    1005    3003
3003    1006    2003
```

This data is arranged in a single row to facilitate removal of duplicates coming in sequence as below:

```
6001    1001    3001    1002    2001    1003    3002    1004    2002    1005    3003    1006    2003    1007    3004    1008    6002    2001    1009
```

Further, this is arranged in the following format:

```
6001    2003    1012    3006
1001    1007    2005    1018
3001    3004    1013    2002
1002    1008    3010    2005
2001    6002    1014    1019
1003    2001    2006    3008
3002    1009    1015    1020
1004    3005    3009    2006
2002    1010    1016    
1005    2004    2003    
3003    1011    2004    
1006    3007    1017
```

Please help me convert this code to use an array instead of saving data to cells in different sheets.

```
Sub ARRANGE()

Dim InputRng As Range, OutRng As Range
Dim row As Integer
Dim rng As Range, j As Long
Dim lastRow As Long


Set InputRng = Sheet1.Range("A1:C20") 'A1 to C20 range is selected for operation

Set OutRng = Sheet2.Cells(1, 1) 'Cell A2 on another sheet

'---as indicated below data is converted to single row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
xRows = InputRng.Rows.Count
xcols = InputRng.Columns.Count
For i = 1 To xRows
    InputRng.Rows(i).Copy OutRng
    Set OutRng = OutRng.Offset(0, xcols + 0)

Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

' duplicates comming one after other are deleted by below code

row = 0    ' Initialize variable.
For i = 1 To 3 * 20
If Sheet2.Cells(1, i).Value = Sheet2.Cells(1, i + 1).Value Then
Sheet2.Cells(1, i).Delete
End If
Next i


' data is rearranged to creat 12 number of rows and dynamic number of colums
 j = 1

         For i = 1 To Sheet2.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column Step 12
             Set rng = Sheet2.Range(Sheet_Pipe_Config.Cells(1, i), Sheet2.Cells(1, i + 12))
             Sheet3.Cells(1, j).Resize(rng.Count - 1, 1) = Application.Transpose(rng)

            j = j + 1
         Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: I suggest you try something, and come back with any specific problem you encounter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are a few bits of code that may help.

Note: in `Set OutRng = Sheet2.Cells(1, 1) 'Cell A2 on another sheet`, `Cells(1,1)` is cell A1 not A2.

Consider:

```
Dim ValuesFormat1 as Variant

ValuesFormatIn = Sheet1.Range("A1:C20").Value
```

The about statement converts Variant ValuesFormatIn to a two dimensional array and loads all the values from the range to it.  Normally in 2D arrays, the first dimension is for columns and the second is for rows.  For arrays that are read from or are to be written to a worksheet, the dimensions are the other way round.  It is as though ValuesFormatIn was sized so:

```
ReDim ValuesFormatIn(1 To 20, 1 To 3)
```

In your original code, you convert the 3*20 range to a 1*60 range by moving cells a row at a time.  You can use the `ReDim` statement to increase or decrease the number of occurrences of the last dimension but there is no standard function that will convert a 2D, 3*20-element array to a 1D, 60-element array.  If you search for "VBA arrays" you will find VBA routines that will perform such conversions.  However, I am not convinced that is the easiest approach.

Consider:

```
Dim NumColsOut As Long
Const NumRowsOut As Long = 12
Dim ValuesFormatOut As Variant

NumColsOut = (UBound(ValuesFormatIn, 1) * UBound(ValuesFormatIn, 2) _
                                                  + NumRowsOut - 1) \ NumRowsOut
ReDim ValuesFormatOut(1 To NumRowsOut, 1 To NumColsOut)
```

This sizes ValuesFormatOut so it can accept the entire set of input values even if not a single duplicate value was found within the input values.  We can write this array to a worksheet array with trailing entries unused so I believe this would be the easiest approach.

This code would then move the values within array ValuesFormatIn to array ValuesFormatout decarding any value that matches its predecessor.

```
  Dim RowInCrnt As Long
  Dim ColInCrnt As Long
  Dim RowOutCrnt As Long
  Dim ColOutCrnt As Long
  Dim ValueCrnt As Long
  Dim ValueLast As Long

  ValueLast = -1        ' For the code below to work, -1 muat be an inpossible value
  RowOutCrnt = 1
  ColOutCrnt = 1

  For RowInCrnt = 1 To UBound(ValuesFormatIn, 1)
    For ColInCrnt = 1 To UBound(ValuesFormatIn, 2)
      If ValuesFormatIn(RowInCrnt, ColInCrnt) <> "" And _
         IsNumeric(ValuesFormatIn(RowInCrnt, ColInCrnt)) Then
        ValueCrnt = ValuesFormatIn(RowInCrnt, ColInCrnt)
        If ValueLast <> ValueCrnt Then
          ValuesFormatOut(RowOutCrnt, ColOutCrnt) = ValueCrnt
          ValueLast = ValueCrnt
          RowOutCrnt = RowOutCrnt + 1
          If RowOutCrnt > NumRowsOut Then
            ColOutCrnt = ColOutCrnt + 1
            RowOutCrnt = 1
          End If
        End If
      Else
        ' Probably a blank cell
        ValueLast = -1
      End If
    Next
  Next
```

Finally, this code will output ValuesFormatOut

```
' Output ValuesFormatOut
With Sheet2
  .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(NumRowsOut, NumColsOut)).Value = ValuesFormatOut
End With
```

Comment: thanks a lot @Tony I will modify my code and will return... thanks for a experts advice...

Comment: dear @tony-dallimore, it is so great.. this code is working just perfect for me..I avoided to covert this array to 2-D.. Still have small query.. how can I do writing on sheet2 columnwise and not rowwise... valuesformatout to be transposed...?

Comment: @Yogesh.Kale  I believe you can use WorksheetFunction.Transform within the transfer between worksheet and array although I have never tried.  It is the values of `NumRowsOut` and `NumColsOut` that control the dimensions of the output array.  The For-Loops for `RowInCrnt` and `ColInCrnt` control the sequence in which values are extracted from the input array.  The values for `RowOutCrnt` and `ColOutCrnt` control the sequence in which data is output.  By adjusting these you should be able to change the arrangement of the output array to your new requirement.